# MSQL 5.5.32 query not running on remote database in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a query that I am trying to pass to a remote database, and the syntax seems to be correct as I ran it through the SQL client on the server side. The query takes data from a form and is as follows.

```
$query = 'INSERT INTO test_2 VALUES (\' \', $name, $address, $phone, $email, $state, $country, $zip)';
$query_run = mysql_query($query)
```

where the first value is an auto increment ID/index and all variables are constructed using HTML entities and `mysql_real_escape_string` as seen below.

```
$name = htmlentities(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['your_name']));
```

Any reason that this is not querying? it seems to run with the syntax and I even used MSQL's built in PHP generator to make a string of PHP that would work ideally. I feel as though I am not passing the variables correctly to the values parameter. ('', '', etc.) could this be it?

Also, I know `mysql_real_escape_string` is deprecated. Is using the updated `mysqli_real_escape_string()` just as easy as putting an i at the end of the first part?

I am using MSQL V 5.5.32 and I believe the syntax to be correct for this version.

Comment: First \ its an escape character it doesnt belong there.Also for your variables to pe parsed you need double quotes.

Comment: No. it's not correct at all. You're missing quotes around your `$name`, `$address`, blah blah blah. **ANY** string value you're stuffing into sql must be quoted, or it'll be interpreted as a field/table name instead. real_escape_string and the like do **NOT** put in quotes for you. they just escape any html metacharacters.

Comment: I think you need to pass NULL as your first value not an empty string

Comment: $query = 'INSERT INTO test_2 VALUES (' ', "$name" , "$address", "$phone", "$email", "$state", "$country", "$zip")'; returns an internal server error which to my understanding means there is an issue with the PHP code. I seem to remember watching a video where within the quotes periods had to be added before and after the string to concatenate the variable. Is that still needed in 5.5.32?

Comment: You need to use double quotes around the whole string, otherwise variable replacements won't happen. To debug this, just print the query out instead of running it - so you can see what you are passing to the database.

Comment: "internal server error" - since you are developing locally, you should reset your php error reporting settings so you can see real errors on-screen.

Comment: @halfer, when you say the whole string, are you referring to the query or the variable name? Currently when I echo the query it gives me word for word what is in the single quotes including the INSERT and SQL words.

Comment: also I am doing this on a web host. Is that good practice?

Comment: When I say "the whole string", I mean, um, the whole string `:)`. Swap your `$query = '...'` for `$query = "..."` and your variables will be replaced. So, use `mysql_real_escape_string` on its own when doing your `INSERT`, and then use `htmlentities` when you render unsafe columns to the screen.

Comment: If you are working on a web host directly, that's not good practice (it is slow, you probably don't have access to version control tools, and it encourages developers to 'work on live' which is not good at all). Set up a web server and development environment locally.

Comment: Note that you generally should not use `htmlentities` when saving to the database - you should do this when rendering from the database instead. This is partly convention, and partly there are cases where you really do want to store input literally (e.g. when saving HTML).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48817/discussion-between-andrew-l-and-halfer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try identifying the column names in the query excluding the auto increment column:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO test_2 (name, address, phone, email, state, country, zip) 
    VALUES ('$name', '$address', '$phone', '$email', '$state', '$country', '$zip')";
```

Also, you should use the `mysqli` functions, because the `mysql_` functions are deprecated.

The other problem with your query is that you are using variables in a single quoted string therefore the variables will not be recognized.

Comment: Mr. KM thanks for the input. I was thinking of doing this method as well. Could you possibly tell me if just adding an i to the mysql_real_escape_string is enough to call the function? or will I have to update my connection file to be sqli compliant?

Comment: Personally I'd get it working first in its current form, @AndrewL, and then convert it to MySQLi. It's not simply a question of changing a single function name.

Comment: I agree with @halfer, get it to work then start converting to mysqli - the quick start guide has great explanations and examples: http://us3.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.php